# Recyclerview's adapter onCreateViewHolder() method parent.getHeight() return 0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing photo editing app in which i am showing stickers in recycler view.
I am setting inflated view's height and width dynamically as shown in code it work fine in all android os version except nougat.In nougat,parent.getHeight() return 0.I don't want to set height and width static and i don't know what i am doing wrong

```
package com.demo.makefunnyface.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.demo.makefunnyface.R;
import com.demo.makefunnyface.Utils.PojoSticker;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by hp on 9/5/2017.
 */

public class AdapterSticker extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSticker.MyHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<PojoSticker> stickersList = new ArrayList<>();
    OnSelectListener onSelectListener;
    DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ImageLoaderConfiguration imageLoaderConfiguration;

    public AdapterSticker(Context context, List<PojoSticker> stickersList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.stickersList.addAll(stickersList);

        displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true).build();
        imageLoaderConfiguration = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayImageOptions).build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(imageLoaderConfiguration);
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_sticker_layout, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = parent.getHeight();
        layoutParams.width = parent.getHeight();

        //nougat show zero in log
        Log.e("height", "" + parent.getHeight());
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        imageLoader.displayImage(stickersList.get(position).getPath(), holder.imgSticker);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stickersList.size();
    }

    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView imgSticker;

        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgSticker = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgSticker);
            imgSticker.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PojoSticker pojoSticker = stickersList.get(getAdapterPosition());
            if (onSelectListener != null) {
                onSelectListener.onSelected(pojoSticker);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface OnSelectListener {
        void onSelected(PojoSticker pojoSticker);
    }

    public void setSelectListener(OnSelectListener onSelectListener) {
        this.onSelectListener = onSelectListener;
    }

    public int dpToPx(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int tmp = (int) ((dp * displayMetrics.density) + 0.5);
        Log.e("tmp", "" + tmp);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the onCreateViewHolder, is where you add the data to the recyclerview (firing object creation), since at onCreate your views didnt finished measurament, you must calculate it delayed such as onResume.

Comment: It works...Thanks a lot but please clear my confusion that why my old code works on other android os ?

Comment: Well, i usually saw this behaviou since ever, dont know why it works in some androids.

Answer (score 0):

it's because on create your view doesn't exist. Try in your onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e("height", "" + holder.itemView.getHeight());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but it still shows zero..@marcos vasconcelos answer's works

Answer (score 0):

worked for me

try to put the RecyclerView in a layout without any other view inside in your XML, like this example :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <fr.semantic.ecare.app.android.components.utils.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/collect_period" />

<!-- IMPORTANT TO DO -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout> .....
.........
</LinearLayout>
```

and in your activity or your fragment :

```
@Override
    public CollectGlycaemiaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_XML_LAYOUT, parent, false);


        int height = parent.getMeasuredHeight() / 3 ; // if you want to devise the height exactly
        int width = parent.getMeasuredWidth();
        view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(width, height));

        return new CollectGlycaemiaViewHolder(view);
    }
```

hope it's helps future developpers

Answer (score 0):

I passed the screen width through the constructor of my adapter.

```
public HorizontalAdapter(HorizontalItem[] list, int screenWidth)
```

```
HorizontalAdapter adapter = new HorizontalAdapter(list, getScreenWidth())
```

```
private int getScreenWidth(){
    WindowManager windowManager = requireActivity().getWindowManager();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    return displayMetrics.widthPixels;
}
```

And inside the adapter's `onCreateViewHolder` set it to the percent of the screen you would like.

e.g `33%` of the screen width.

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewholder_horizontal_item, parent, false);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = itemView.getLayoutParams();

        //Set to the percent you want here.
        layoutParams.width = (int) (screenWidth * 0.33f);

        itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```